# Is it possible to write NUnit tests in Powershell?

Tags: unit-testing, powershell, nunit

I would like to code an NUnit test in Powershell.

Consider the following NUnit test in C#:

```
[TestCase(0)]
[TestCase(1)]
public void YabaDabaDoo(int x)
{
    Assert.IsTrue(x > -1);
}
```

I would like to be able to express the same intent in Powershell. Obviously, the devil is in details, but there are valid scenarios when it is required to write tests in some scripting language.

Now, maybe NUnit is not the right choice, in which case what is? Better be on a par with NUnit.

Comment: Powershell has pester to test Powershell scripts, NUnit is used to test managed code. You can use Powershell to run NUnit test runner and by extension tests.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to code an NUnit test in Powershell.

No. differing technologies.

Powershell has [Pester](https://github.com/pester/Pester) to test Powershell scripts, while NUnit is used to test managed code.

Pester features include a test runner, assertions, mocking and more.

Learn more about Pester at their [wiki guide](https://github.com/Pester/Pester/wiki) to get more details.

Powershell scripts can be used to run NUnit test runner and by extension tests.

For example

```
$ProjectDir = "."
$PackagesDir = "$ProjectDir\packages"
$OutDir = "$ProjectDir\bin\Debug"

# Install NUnit Test Runner
$nuget = "$ProjectDir\.nuget\nuget.exe"
& $nuget install NUnit.Runners  -Version 2.6.2 -o $PackagesDir

# Set nunit path test runner
$nunit = "$ProjectDir\packages\NUnit.Runners.2.6.2\tools\nunit-console.exe"

#Find tests in OutDir
$tests = (Get-ChildItem $OutDir -Recurse -Include *Tests.dll)

# Run tests
& $nunit /noshadow /framework:"net-4.0" /xml:"$OutDir\Tests.nunit.xml" $tests
```

Answer (score 2):

NUnit is as others have mentioned for managed code. I'd recommend using the [Pester](https://github.com/pester/Pester)-module for unit testing PowerShell code. It's available on GitHub and also available by default in Windows 10. Ex:

```
Describe "YabaDabaDoo" {
    $cases = @{x=-1},@{x=0},@{x=1}

    It "<x> should be greater than -1" -TestCases $cases {
        param ([int]$x)
        $x | Should -BeGreaterThan -ExpectedValue -1
    }    
}
```

Output:

```
Describing YabaDabaDoo
  [-] -1 should be greater than -1 113ms
    Expected '-1' to be greater than the actual value, but got -1.
    6:         $x | Should -BeGreaterThan -ExpectedValue -1
  [+] 0 should be greater than -1 30ms
  [+] 1 should be greater than -1 15ms
```